# What are the best javascript array library/utility/extensions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, utility

I've been using the dojo array utilties, but I'm not entirely happy with the limited number of features. Is there any really extensive well-written javascript array utility library or extension?

I'd be hoping for something similar in scope to the collections extension in the C# API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd be hoping for something similar to the collection extension in the
>   C# API.

Not sure exactly what you mean by "array utility/extension", but [LINQ for JavaScript](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/) looks pretty cool. It implements many of the collection-related extension methods found in .NET.

Comment: Ah this looks like pretty great. I will have to give it a try.

Comment: I meant something similar to the methods and extension methods shown on here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx , this is just to give you an idea.

Answer (score 11):

Check out [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/)

Comment: Ahh, beat me to it! underscore is FANTASTIC.

Comment: Note: Removed my stuff about LINQ since @Tim Medora might have posted it before I edited my answer to include it (not sure).

Comment: Boiler.js is another good one. ;) http://www.boilerjs.com

Comment: I use underscore too - but evaluating most performant one for a high end product dev.